# Obtain a Google search results URL for a specific search string

Tags: javascript

I need to find a way to create get the Google search results page for a specific search string. (for example, `site:stackoverflow.com javascript`). Is it possible to do this using Javascript?

This is the URL of the search results page for the above search string:

`https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site:stackoverflow.com+javascript&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+javascript&gs_l=hp.3...13833.13833.0.14821.1.1.0.0.0.0.75.75.1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.RW1esyXtgVY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=52e43fe95f7f41ff&bpcl=35466521&biw=1366&bih=626`

Comment: I finally found a solution: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39818/how-should-i-write-the-url-for-a-specific-google-search-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Custom Search API?

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Should have what you want...

It's either that or you scrape the page if you somehow know the actual HTML structure of the results...although I'm sure there are other solutions.

Comment: I found a much easier solution. See here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39818/how-should-i-write-the-url-for-a-specific-google-search-query

Answer (score -1):

You can use ajax to perform a curl request server-side with PHP (for example). You can't do that just with javascript because it's considered cross-site scripting.

Comment: But that's what RESTful APIs are for :)